# eclipse CDT Plugin development : How to get the class name which has a declaration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing an eclipse plugin based on CDT API.

Suppose I've following C++ code

```
   class EventEnum
   {
   public:
      enum e { 
         E_CompleteDisconnectSuccess = 1, 
         E_CreateBtAdapterNoSuccess = 2, 
         E_CreateBtAdapterSuccess = 3, 
      };
   };
```

Using following `ASTVisitor` visitor method I can find the enum declaration

```
public int visit(IASTDeclaration declaration) {
    if (declaration instanceof IASTSimpleDeclaration) {

        IASTDeclSpecifier specifier = ((IASTSimpleDeclaration)declaration).getDeclSpecifier();

        if (specifier instanceof IASTEnumerationSpecifier) {
            IASTEnumerationSpecifier enumSpecifier = (IASTEnumerationSpecifier)specifier;
            // Get the current enumeration name
            String enumerationName = enumSpecifier.getName().toString();

            System.out.println("Found enum : " + enumerationName);
        }
    }
    return PROCESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

**Question :** How can I get the class name which contains the found enum declaration, in my case it will be `EventEnum` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on my own, probably for someone it will be usefull, so I'm posting it here

```
if (enumSpecifier.getParent() instanceof CPPASTSimpleDeclaration)
{
    if (enumSpecifier.getParent().getParent() instanceof CPPASTCompositeTypeSpecifier)
    {
        CPPASTCompositeTypeSpecifier firstLevelClass = (CPPASTCompositeTypeSpecifier)enumSpecifier.getParent().getParent();
        return firstLevelClass.getName().toString();
    }
}
```